# Hataras Nedarim for 12 yr old boy

Tags: minor-katan-child, rosh-hashanah-new-year, nedarim-shevuot

When a boy reaches 12 years old, his nedarim (vows) are considered to be binding. However, I don't believe I've ever seen a 12 year old boy make [Hataras Nedarim](http://e.yeshiva.org.il/ask/?cat=447) on Erev Rosh HaShanah. Is there a reason why they don't, or is it done and I have just not seen it?

(Please feel free to edit this question or add comments to expand on the sources that I have purposely left out because of a lack of knowledge.)

Answer (score 2):

The Shaarim Metzuyanim Bhalacha (128:24) is quoted as saying that although a 12 year old can make a neder, they lack the ability to make hataras nedarim. See also Piskei Teshuva 581/18.

There are others who disagree, and I’ve seen some 12 year olds do hataras nedarim but they cannot join on the “Beis din” so it’s somewhat uncomfortable for them.

Comment: More importantly (since mass hatarat nedarim is sort of a joke anyway), can they give the modaa and if so they should do it immediately on their birthday (and girls at 11) not wait for erev rosh hashana.

Comment: The logic that they state is that the daas is only enough to make the neder but they don’t have daas to understand nullification. So it would seem that modaa wouldn’t help either

Comment: The modaa isn't based in hatara as much as in tnai so I don't follow your logic.

Comment: I’m saying that they don’t really have daas, only to make nedarim. There’s no reason to assume they have daas for modaa

Comment: If they can make a neder, then they can make a neder on tnai, then they can make a tnai hours beforehand. It's all the same daas.